# delete all documents in MongoDB collection where condition is satisfied

Tags: python, mongodb, collections, pymongo

I'm a beginner in pymongo and flask and I have a users collection with a user instance like :

```
user = { "Email" : "user@gmail.com" , "Comments" : ["good user", "bad user "] }
```

I want to iterate through my users collection and if any string in the Comments array of each user contains the word "good" I want to delete the specific comment . However I am a beginner and I do not know the pymongo syntax very well to do that . With my code below no existing comment is deleted :

```
                i = users.find()
                for customer in i: #for every user in collection 
                    for comment in customer['Comments']:  #for every comment in the comments field
                        if "good" in comment:
                            print("comment found") #if comment is found print this 
                            users.update_one( {"Comments": "good"} , {"$pull": {"Comments": comment}})
```

I would appreciate your help with guiding me to solve this issue . Thank you in advance .

Comment: Your question is ambiguous, title is saying `delete all documents` where as in description it's mentioned `delete the specific comment`, could you be more specific.

Comment: @ngShravil.py I mean to delete all documents that satisfy specifc condition . I solved it anyway . Thank you for the response

Comment: If you solved it pleases post your own answer or close the question.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED :

```
                     i = users.find()
                    for customer in i:
                        for comment in customer['Comments']:
                            if "good" in comment:
                                print(comment) 
                                users.update_one( {"Comments": comment } ,
                                {"$pull": {"Comments": comment}})
```